# How do I configure prettier to behave in a specific way for Vue.js template syntax?

Tags: html, vue.js, formatting, prettier

I want to customize a specific behavior in [Prettier](https://prettier.io/). I'm wondering if there's a quick way to implement below solution without having to write my own parser.

**My .prettierrc.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
   $schema: 'https://json.schemastore.org/prettierrc',
   semi: true,
   tabWidth: 3,
   singleQuote: true,
   printWidth: 100,
   trailingComma: 'es5',
   bracketSpacing: true,
   bracketSameLine: false,
   arrowParens: 'always',
   vueIndentScriptAndStyle: false,
   singleAttributePerLine: true,
};
```

**Vue template (HTML) that I want to format:**

```html
<template>
   <a href="https://vitejs.dev/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Vite</a>
</template>
```

**Current outcome:**

```
<template>
   <a
      href="https://vitejs.dev/"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"
      >Vite</a
   >
</template>
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
<template>
   <a
      href="https://vitejs.dev/"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"
   >
      Vite
   </a>
</template>
```

Is there a way to achieve above desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [HTML Whitespace Sensitivity Setting](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity).

https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting:

> As you may notice during daily HTML works, the following two cases
> won't produce the same output:
>
> |  | **html** | **output** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | with spaces | `1<b> 2 </b>3` | 1 **2** 3 |
> | without spaces | `1<b>2</b>3` | 1**2**3 |
>
> For this reason, we cannot safely format

```
<a href="https://prettier.io/">Prettier is an opinionated code formatter.</a>
```

> into

```
<a href="https://prettier.io/">
  Prettier is an opinionated code formatter.
</a>
```

> since it may modify the displayed output in the browser.
>
> Instead of breaking your code or just doing nothing, we introduce
> whitespace-sensitive formatting, which:
>
> - follows the default CSS display value for every element to identify if
>   the whitespace inside it is significant,
> - and wraps the tags in such a
>   way as to avoid adding or removing significant whitespace.

I hope this helps :)